# nodejs sync read write on socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, synchronization

I would like to writeSync readSync on socket using nodejs.
Someone on irc told me that is not possible.
But nodejs offers setNoDelay(false), socket.pause() and socket.resume() which allow me to use the socket fd in blocking mode.

here is an example:

```
client.on('connect', function() {
    client.setNoDelay(false);
}); 

[...]

var b = new Buffer(10240);
client.pause();
fs.writeSync(client._handle.fd, JSON.stringify(req)+'\n');
var r = fs.readSync(client._handle.fd, b, null, b.length);
client.resume();
```

In this example i got EGAIN on read and EPIPE on write.

Comment: Those are two different things. File stream is synchronous but socket is not. You cannot use fs functions on a native node socket. If it were a socket file then yes. But node has underlying async library to deal with this. This is like hijackng the socket stream.

Comment: thanks. but this is really useful. actually there is no way todo what i want ?

Comment: No, this was done intentionally. Synchronous operations are blocking, which is not what node developers wanted.

Comment: yes thanks but as i said sometime that could be useful

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlinkwrapper
Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996603